# Configure read preference for mongodbs dbrefs in spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'd like to configure the read preference of the dbrefs, when the reference points to a specific collection, without setting a general read preference for the container collection or for the referenced one.

Is there a way to do this, using spring boot 1.3.2 (spring-data-mongodb 1.8.2)?